# Python Threading for Camera

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to put the camera footage into a different thread as the `cv2.wait()` does not work correctly anymore for access keys even when using an '& and hexadecimal'.

Does anyone know what I have done wrong with the daemon thread I have created for displaying camera footage in the main as when placed in the main while loop it fails while loop?

How do I use a thread to continuously display camera footage in my while loop in the main program?

> quote ***My thread for the `ViewCamera` function isn't working right - can anyone help?***

```
from djitellopy import Tello            
# Access the telopy libray.
import cv2, math, time

from time import sleep, perf_counter
from threading import Thread

stop = True


def ViewCamera():
    global stop
    
    while stop == True:
        try:
            #camera window
            img = frame_read.frame
            cv2.imshow("drone", img)
            
            print ('thread test')        

        except Exception as e:
                print ("Cerror is : ,", e)
       
    

drone = Tello()
'''
create an instance of the Tellopy libray

drone.connect()                         #connect to drone using wifi

drone.streamon()
#make use of a data stream to drone to pass on keyboard commands
#frame_read = drone.get_frame_read()     #read cammera data using frame per frame rate
'''


       
key = 0

# drone.takeoff()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ('main program')
    
# Create a camera thread - runs in background.
t1 = Thread(target=ViewCamera, args=())
t1.daemon = True 
print('starting thread')
t1.start()
 

while True: 
        
    key = ord(input('please enter letter'))   
    if key == ord('j'):
        drone.land()
        print('stopping thread')
        stop = False
        
        break
    elif key == ord('w'):   # Forward
        drone.move_forward(30)
        print('moving forwards')
    elif key == ord('s'):   # Move backwards
        drone.move_back(30)
    elif key == ord('a'):   # Move left
        drone.move_left(30)
    elif key == ord('d'):   # Move right
        drone.move_right(30)
    elif key == ord('e'):   # Rotate right
        drone.rotate_clockwise(30)
    elif key == ord('q'):   # Rotate left
        drone.rotate_counter_clockwise(30)
    elif key == ord('r'):   # Move up
        drone.move_up(30)   
    elif key == ord('f'):   # Move down
        drone.move_down(30)
        
print('stopping thread')
t1.join()     

drone.land()
```

The threading daemon isn't seeming to work it should be running in background and  continually allowing the camera images in a window to be viewed - any ideas why it is not?

Comment: There is no code interacting with cv2 here (you have a commented imshow, but nothing that reads from camera or waiting) and so it's impossible to know what is the actual problem. Please describe the problem, and include a full snippet (i.e. with imports, etc.)

Comment: hi I have updated code so you can see everything thing, with import of cv2 library too

Comment: This code still has syntax errors (`camera window` is not valid python code) and is incomplete (there is no code calling any interaction with the window, reading a frame, or calling `cv2.wait`). We can't help with incomplete code. Please try the code from the tutorial (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-capture-video-from-camera/) and see if it works? Alternatively, provide a fuller explanation of the issue (short *working* snippet of code, and what happens)